# Upgraded to Django 4.2, import storages module failed

Tags: python, django, pycharm, backend, python-import

I recently upgraded Django 4.2 and was applying storage change to my project.
Ran into an import error with the storage module.

My code for import

```
from django.core.files.storage import storages
```

The error I am getting is

```
error: Module 'django.core.files.storage' has no attribute 'storages'
```

I double checked the package versions.
I tried to re-install the requirements.
Both pycharm and mypy threw me the error.
I tried to import that module in shell and it worked fine.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/67579). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: make sure you are in right env

Comment: @iklinac I believe I am, how do I make sure that?